# Break D3 objects into rows

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 script that creates a circle for every point in my data and then places the circles next to each other. How can I place the circles into a new row after, say, five circles (or after the graphic hits a specific width)? The image below shows what I am trying to accomplish. Code and JS fiddle also included.

Thanks so much for any help that you can provide.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Js Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/amarton/Ly1go0sp/1/

````
    {
      "category": "apple",
      "step": 1,
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    },
    {
      "category": "banana",
      "step": 2,
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    },
    {
      "category": "grape",
      "step": 3,
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    },
    {
      "category": "apple",
      "step": 3,
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    },
    {
      "category": "banana",
      "step": 2,
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    },
    {
      "category": "grape",
      "step": 1,
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    }
   ]

async function draw(){
    //Get data
   const data = jsonData;

//apend the svg container to the div
var svgContainer = d3.select("#myChart").append("svg")
.attr("viewBox", `0 0 500 500`)


//append the circles to the svg 
var circles = svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
    //this calls the data
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")

//draw the circles    
var circleAttributes = circles
    //increment the x posiiton
    .attr("cx", function(e, counter){return 50  * (counter) + 50})
    .attr("cy", 30)
    .attr("r", 20 )

}
  
draw()```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nouHP.png
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `cx` exceeds the `viewBox` edge. You can then increase `cy` to place the circle in different rows:

```
// the width and height of the view box
var viewBoxEdge = 500;
// the x/y offset between the center of two circles
var circleOffset = 50;

//apend the svg container to the div
var svgContainer = d3.select("#myChart").append("svg")
.attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${viewBoxEdge} 500`)

// ...

//draw the circles    
var circleAttributes = circles
    //increment the x posiiton
    .attr("cx", function(e, counter){
        // this will 'return' cx to the horizontal start of the row when exceeding width - think of this as a 'column index'
        var cx = (50  * counter) % (viewBoxEdge - circleOffset) + circleOffset;
        return cx;
      
      })
    .attr("cy", function(e, counter) {
        // this will move the circle to the next row when exceeding the width - think of this as a 'row index'
        var cy = Math.floor(50 * counter / (viewBoxEdge - circleOffset)) * circleOffset + circleOffset;
        return cy;
    
    })
    .attr("r", 20 )
```

```js
var jsonData = [
    {
      "category": "apple",
      "step": 1,
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    },
    {
      "category": "banana",
      "step": 2,
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    },
    {
      "category": "grape",
      "step": 3,
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    },
    {
      "category": "apple",
      "step": 3,
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    },
    {
      "category": "banana",
      "step": 2,
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    },
    {
      "category": "grape",
      "step": 1,
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    },{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}
   ]

async function draw(){
    //Get data
   const data = jsonData;

// the width and height of the view box
var viewBoxEdge = 500;
// the x/y offset between the center of two circles
var circleOffset = 50;

//apend the svg container to the div
var svgContainer = d3.select("#myChart").append("svg")
.attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${viewBoxEdge} 500`)


//append the circles to the svg 
var circles = svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
    //this calls the data
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")

//draw the circles    
var circleAttributes = circles
    // increment the x posiiton
    .attr("cx", function(e, counter){
        // this will 'return' cx to the horizontal start of the row when exceeding width
        var cx = (50  * counter) % (viewBoxEdge - circleOffset) + circleOffset;
        return cx;
      
      })
    .attr("cy", function(e, counter) {
        // this will move the circle to the next row when exceeding the width
        var cy = Math.floor(50 * counter / (viewBoxEdge - circleOffset)) * circleOffset + circleOffset;
        return cy;
    
    })
    .attr("r", 20 )

}

draw();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="myChart"></div>
```

**Use HTML Elements**

`d3` is not limited to SVG manipulation. You can manipulate the entire element tree of `html`.

If the visualization you are trying to build can be done in html only, do it in html!

You could use [`display: flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to layout the circles over multiple rows.
This has two advantages:

1. You could define responsive css to handle different viewports. Doing this in css is easier than writing your own `d3` 'layout engine'.
2. The browser changes the layout when the viewport changes (resize window)

```js
var jsonData = [
    {
      "category": "apple",
      "step": 1,
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    },
    {
      "category": "banana",
      "step": 2,
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    },
    {
      "category": "grape",
      "step": 3,
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    },
    {
      "category": "apple",
      "step": 3,
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    },
    {
      "category": "banana",
      "step": 2,
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    },
    {
      "category": "grape",
      "step": 1,
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    },{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}
   ]
   
   var circlesContainer = d3.select('.circles');
   
   circlesContainer = circlesContainer
       .selectAll('.circle')
       .data(jsonData)
       .enter()
       .append('div')
       .attr('class', 'circle')
```

```css
.circles {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.circles .circle {
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="circles"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Christoph. This is tremendous.